# xlwings: terminate VBA execution upon Python error

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

I have an Excel VBA subroutine that calls a Python function with the xlwings `RunPython` command. If the called Python function terminates due to an error, then a pop-up with the Python error traceback appears in Excel. However afterwards Excel happily continues with execution of the remainder of the VBA subroutine.

How can I force the VBA subroutine to terminate immediately after the Python function from `RunPython` raises an error?

Comment: See [discussion of the topic here](https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/2125)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RunPython` returns -1 in case of an error. Therefore a solution is:

```
return_code = RunPython("import hello; hello.world()")
If return_code = -1 Then
    End
End If
```